# Account Frozen wit Phanthom wallet

Tags: wallet

I purchased a coin CDUM6TUwwAfuKxE5jQVGfAaGXd8AJFpwQJM5XASXVAZ2 paired wit SOL through Phanthom wallet on Jupiter exchange,pooled on Fluxbeam.
After buying when I wanted to sell there’s an error keep coming ‘Account is frozen’, this occurred only for this token and I was able to trade other tokens.
But when I checked trading wit Solifare i was able to trade, so I assume it’s because of Phanthaom wallet the message keep coming and I couldn’t swap on any platform.
Now the token dipped and couldn’t sell when i wanted to.

TX

https://solscan.io/tx/5mNi5UbATZB7mwPD32rWUwmN11JUPD5RP7ZrfLk5UpXfzBcfVVogV9FWYuGoJpj58cTe5Q5AeMMaLtTQ9pyv6gWZ

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is aimed at helping developers build apps on Solana. To ask questions about Phantom, please reach out to their support.

Answer (score -3):

When I created a second Account within the Phanthom it works, but i couldn’t transfer the token for a swap. It’s clearly an issue with PHANTHOM Wallet,missed the opportunity and incurred lost.

It look like Phanthom wallet has some sort of control over my wallet.